# Azure 'Set up deployment from source control' via Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, azure-web-app-service, setup-deployment, powershell-cmdlet

I want to script an Azure WebSite creation and deployment using git and Powershell.

Via the cmdlet, I can create the website and change the hosting plan mode.
But I don't know, using the powershell cmdlets, how to script the 'Set up deployment from source control' WebSite operation of the Azure WebSite.

- Is there any cmdlet(s) available(s) to perform this kind of operation ?
- Which one and where can I find the documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to enable the git repository on the website then use this:

```
new-azurewebsite mynewwebsite -git
```

If you want to enable github integration then you can use something like this:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
new-azurewebsite mynewwebsite -github -githubrepository youraccount/yourreponame -githubcredentials $creds
```

In both cases you should be in the directory where you want to create your local copy of the repository and make sure that git.exe is in the path.